# C++ Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am new to c++ and was trying to save text into a text file. However, when I run the program, I keep getting this error from eclipse and could not figure out what went wrong:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "StorageSave::execute(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >)", referenced from:
 _main in SpendTracker.o
```

Here are my codes:

StorageSave.h:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "Account/Account.h"

#ifndef STORAGE_STORAGESAVE_H_
#define STORAGE_STORAGESAVE_H_

class StorageSave {
public:
    StorageSave();
    virtual ~StorageSave();

    std::string execute(std::string allData);
};

#endif /* STORAGE_STORAGESAVE_H_ */
```

StorageSave.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "StorageSave.h"

StorageSave::StorageSave() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

}

StorageSave::~StorageSave() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}

std::string execute(std::string allData) {

    std::ofstream file("hey.txt");
    //std::ofstream *fileptr = &file;

    if(!file.is_open()) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file." << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::string textData = "test";
        file << textData;
        file.close();
    }

    return "";
}
```

Comment: How are you calling it in `main()`?

Comment: StorageSave storageSave;
storageSave.execute("");

Comment: Oooooh never mind, I think I see the problem. It means the linker can't find the function with that name. You forgot to define `execute()` with `StorageSave::execute()` in your cpp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should turn

```
std::string execute(std::string allData) {
```

into

```
std::string StorageSave::execute(std::string allData) {
```

You are using execute as member function and declared it, but is implemented as free function

Comment: Oops that's a careless mistake